# Ruby task uses 97 %CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

My ruby application uses about 97 %CPU which eventually gets killed. The program is reading files from the folder and if a file name exists in the database, it skips it and checks another file. While executing this procedure, application usually gets killed.

```
COMMAND      %CPU
ruby         96.5
```

Even if I insert almost all files and try to lunch an application again (because it was killed), system tends to kill it even sooner. How can I decrease the %CPU?

```
task :process_data, [:data_directory] => :environment do |_task, args|
    # add data to a database
    saver = CsvToSqlSaver.new
    saver.fill_files_names

    Dir.foreach(args.data_directory) do |filename|
      # if not present in records already we read it
      Base.logger.info "> Found #{filename}."
      next if saver.files_names.to_s.include?(filename) ||
              !filename.include?('csv')
      Base.logger.info "> Reading #{filename}."

      begin
        saver.generate_db_rows_from_csv_file(args.data_directory, filename)
      # handle Malformed .csv exception
      rescue CSV::ArgumentError, CSV::MalformedCSVError => e
       Base.logger.info e.message
        next
      end # we continue csv file loop?

      unless integrator.insert_data_to_database
       Base.logger.info '> No new data saved.'
      end
    end
end
```

This is fill_files_names:

```
 def fill_files_names
      @files_names = []
      files_names = MyFilesTable.select(:filename).distinct
      files_names.each do |row|
        @files_names.push(row[:filename])
      end
 end
```

This is Base:

```
class Base
    class << self
      attr_accessor :logger
    end
    @logger ||= Logger.new(STDERR)
end
```

This is generate_db_rows_from_csv_file

```
def generate_db_rows_from_csv_file(directory, filename)
      @incoming_data = []

      CSV.foreach("#{directory}/#{filename}",
                  headers: true, quote_char: "\x00") do |csv_record|
        # if invalid record, go further
        next if record_invalid?(csv_record)

        generate_row_in_the_database(csv_record, filename)
      end
end
```

Comment: Why does your OS kill applications in the first place?

Comment: I have no idea. I believe that the problem will be solved if I decrease %CPU

Comment: CPU load is most probably is not the issue (unless you're having a hardware failure due to overheat), how many files do you feed? I think you may be running out of file descriptors

Comment: I would argue that it would be ridiculous when an OS kill processes because they use the CPU. Using the CPU is actually a good sign: The process does something and it is not blocked by IO. I would be worried when the process takes too much memory or doesn't make progress? Does he? Does the process still send entries to the log file? Do the entries look legit?

Comment: The funny thing is that the logger prints information on the screen without inserting it to the actual log file. Even if I redirect the output with >> file.log (in terminal) it still creates file in log/ folder and saves there information about sql procedures. No such thing like "> Reading #{filename}.".

About the information there - it looks legit no information about potential errors. I take last 50 rows to examine them and nothing.

Comment: I've just noticed that it uses a lot of memory:
MEM
153M+

Comment: 135 MB is not a lot of memory. Is this on your local machine or, say, some kind of shared hosting?

Comment: It's a remote machine.